# Is a variable in a bash script a pointer? or implemented as a pointer in C?

Tags: bash

I am learning basic bash script.

Suppose such a minimal codes:

```
$ for i in draft/*; do 
    file $i; 
done
draft/first.html: ASCII text
draft/second.html: ASCII text
draft/third.html: ASCII text
```

I noticed `$i`, prefix $ to i, very likely to C's *pointer to dereference to its value.

Is variable in bash script a pointer? or implemented as a pointer in C details?

Comment: Thinking in bash in terms of C is too much abstraction for me. My analogy is: think in bash in terms of C preprocessor. `draft/*` get's expanded by all files in draft directory, the `$i` get's expanded by the elements in the for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're onto something, although the Bash scripting language does not have the concept of a pointer. What is happening here is that you declare a variable named `i` and then **expand** the string `$i` to the value of the variable. In [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) this is called "parameter expansion", but most people call it "variable expansion" or "variable substitution".

Answer (score 1):

`$` is just an indicator that its a variable per the language definition.

Layers between bash and its implementation in C are quite deep and its probably best not to try to think in terms of pointers when doing bash scripting.